# Visual Studios 11 beta bug: F5 doesn't run app?

Tags: visual-studio

I get this bug VERY often.

When opening a solution or after a compile pressing the "Debug" hotkey (F5, i set it to C# keyboard mapping) the IDE will not run the app. Ctrl F5 will run it (runs outside of the IDE w/o a debugger) but F5 wont work itself. If i click the button in the IDE to run it still won't run. I have to let it sit for 40+ seconds before F5 will work. When the app closes I cant always start it in debug mode again. Something is weird. When i first install visual studios 11beta it didnt do this (I have updated visual studios with one of their patches tho).

Does anyone know a fix? I'm running on windows-7

Comment: Report it over at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio Maybe someone has even already reported it and posted a workaround.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I cant submit a bug! there will no longer be exactly 1337 results for 'F5'. But in all seriousness they probably know about it or close it as not reproducible since i cant exactly reproduce it. In fact thats exactly what they did http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/720516/debug-f5-has-no-effect-on-a-console-application